# Set passcode on IOS Programatically

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, passcode

Is there anyway to set passcode on ios without manual intervention

Ways I have tried

- Searched for Private APIs to set passcode, but couldn't find any
- Checked Apple MDM

  - It has a command to Clear passcode but not for setting

Can set passcode through XCUI Automation, but looking for a less time taking solution

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to do that otherwise apps would set user's passcode and users would be unable to unlock their device because a 3rd party app has changed passcode.